# Angular js 2 routing is happening but nothing changing in url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Angular js 2 routing is happening but nothing changing in url

hai all,

Am new to angular  js 2  and i have created routing example with three tab they are different type of forms in angular js 2..
1.Template driven
2.The model driven
3.The model driven with form builder

[image]

issue is when i click another tab file content changes but url,validation are not working

I have uploaded entire content in github
Am glad if someone helps me to clean that code also.
Am am also looking for contributor for that form templates

Thanks in advance 
here is the code for routing in app.component.ts

```
<nav>
            <a routerLink="/angulartemplateform" routerLinkActive="active">Angular Forms Using Template</a>
            <a routerLink="/angularmoduleformdata" routerLinkActive="active">Angular Forms Using Model</a>
            <a routerLink="/angularmodulebuilder" routerLinkActive="active">Angular Forms Using Form Builder</a>
          </nav>              
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Github Url ::https://github.com/selva1990kumar/AngularJS-Forms

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have not set any for empty route path

```
const routes: Routes = [
     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'angulartemplateform', pathMatch: 'full' },
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      { path: 'angulartemplateform', component: EmployeeListComponent},
      { path: 'angularmoduleformdata', component: EmployeeDetailComponent},
      { path: 'angularmodulebuilder', component: EmployeeFormComponent},


    ]
```

Comment: { path: '', redirectTo: 'angulartemplateform', pathMatch: 'full' }, i have tried the above code but its not working also problem is it goes to the angularmoduleformdata,angularmodulebuilder link and return back to angulartemplateform

Comment: angulartemplateform:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/app/app-routing.module.ts' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.
popup.js:121 Uncaught ReferenceError: XML is not defined
    at popup.js:121
(anonymous) @ popup.js:121
core.umd.js:210 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.   This is the error which i get when i load project

Comment: yes. the error message is very straight forward beyond this what you want from me :)!

Comment: thank u so much Aravind boss i have fixed it .am really sorry for late reply